# Dreamweaver's build app function in cs 5.5 breaks if there is php code?

Tags: php, android, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

For javascript and html files only, Dreamweaver's build app for android function seems to work great in cs 5.5. But when any php code is put in (for authentication, or for ajaxing in web service returns ) it seems that the android app just displays broken php code instead of executing it. When building the app, Dreamweaver won't even let you use a root php file in the project; it only seems to only accept html files.

Am I doing something wrong? Building apps out of web language-based files seems a lot less useful if server-side code isn't allowed.

Are there any other alternatives? Titanium studio looks really complicated, but I'm willing to read the docs if it's worth the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSeffff8bffc80208478c8d43312e240fe0ad-8000.html

Indeed it only packages HTML, CSS and Javascript into an Android or iOS package.
I'm afraid you'll have to learn real Android development if you want something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver will package the files up just like you asked, however, the destination system is what runs the code. Android doesn't execute the PHP within the app. Your app has to connect with a remote server that is to handle the log in. Thinks of two separate apps, one on the phone and one on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't execute the PHP within the app. This is because PHP is a server side client and Not client side. Unless they create some inbuit servers within phones from which native apps can tap into. One option you can use is to use html files and within them, create links to php files which are in online servers so as to have your scripts executed.